# Find a object key from a HashMap

Tags: java, collections

I have a HashMap having key as my own object and key as ArrayList of String. Is there a way to get the key object from the map which is equal to another object without iterating the map. Please note that my object has implemented equals & hashcode. And it only uses 2 attribute of the class to compare. The another object which I am trying to find in the keys of the map has those 2 attribute equal but the other attributes may be different in the key of the map.

```
//The actual map
private HashMap<FileDetail, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<FileDetail, ArrayList<String>>();
//object to search in above map without iteration.
FileDetail file = some object;
```

I want to get the reference of the "file" object in the keys of the map.

Comment: What information do you want to use to find your key?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to retrieve the key itself not the value referenced by the key?

Comment: Yes I want to retrieve the key first then based on the status of the key object use the value.

Comment: I would prefer not to use any external API in my case. I possible please help with java API classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't do that. `HashMap` are supposed to work the other way : you have the key, you're looking for the object.

If you have an object and you want to find the key, there's probably something wrong in your logic and your looking in a wrong direction to solve your problem.

Comment: Its like I have a map having the key object being processed by some task which changes the state. And I have another task which has a fresh object. So before sending my fresh object for processing I want to check the status from the map. If it is already processed then I am going to ignore the fresh object received from some where.

Comment: You are right Krtek & thanks. The map are supposed to be based on key. At last I decided to iterate because I cannot add any new library.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to iterate over the keySet, then you can use [Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [BiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html). A biMap has an inverse view which is another bimap containing reversed keys and values. This is how you would use it:

```
BiMap<FileDetail, ArrayList<String>> biMap = HashBiMap.create();

//object to search in above map without iteration.
FileDetail file = some object;

FileDetail key = biMap.inverse().get(biMap.get(file));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do this without iteration over the keySet (e.g. because the map is very large), I suggest storing both the key and the list as values in the map. Either create some specific class encapsulating both, or use a simple pair class. The map would look like:

```
Map<FileDetail, Pair<FileDetail, List<String>>>
```

If you can't change the type of the map, you can use a second `Map<FileDetail, FileDetail>` where key and value are always the same objects.

Answer (score 1):

This question is five years old, but I had the same question just today, and found this page. I thought I'd share the solution I decided upon using, which is not described in any of the existing answers and avoids iterating over all the keys in the map. (Please be gentle; this is my first posting on SO. It's tough finding questions I can answer that don't already have answers. Moreover, every question I've had to date has already been asked on SO. I've been using SO for years, with no ability to comment or vote on answers.)

As has been stated already, maps are designed so that when you have a key, you look up a value. That being the case, the answer is to use the key also as the value, so that when you perform a lookup using an arbitrary key, which `equals` your original key but is not necessarily `==` to it, you get back the original key. The issue then, is how to get what you originally intended to be the value.

My solution depends on having control of the class used for the key, and control of the map, with the ability to redefine them, which appears to be the case for the OP. In the OP's example, this would be control of the `FileDetail` class and of the private `map` variable. Assuming such control, the `FileDetail` class would be modified to contain a member variable of type `ArrayList<String>`, which for my sample code below I'll call `list`, with associated setter and getter methods. For the private `map` variable, it would be defined thusly:

```
private HashMap<FileDetail, FileDetail> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Now, when you want to `put` a new `ArrayList<String>` object in the map, assigned to a specific `FileDetail` key, you assign the `ArrayList<String>` object to the `FileDetail`'s `ArrayList<String>` member variable instead, and then place the `FileDetail` object in the `map`.

```
public void putInMap(FileDetail fd, ArrayList<String> al) {
    // Ignoring null conditions for simplicity...
    fd.setList(al);
    map.put(fd, fd);
}
```

Later, when you get some arbitrary `FileDetail` object (one that `equals` the key but isn't necessarily `==` to it), and you want the associated key, it's a matter of doing a normal lookup:

```
FileDetail otherFd = getArbitraryFileDetail();
FileDetail originalKeyFd = map.get(otherFd);
```

And to get the associated `ArrayList<String>` after having performed the above:

```
ArrayList<String> al = originalKeyFd.getList();
```

Certainly this all hinges on the implementations of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the `FileDetail` class, but the OP already had those methods defined as desired.

Hope this helps anyone who, like me, comes to this page with a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for a Bidirectional Map, [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html) includes this as part of the library (im sure there are other imeplementations as well.) A bidirectional map, just as the name implies, is a map but written so as to make looking up by key or by value efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `HashMap` associates a key with a value, not the other way around.

You can retrieve a `Set` of all of the keys using [`HashMap.keySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29), or alternatively iterate over all of the entries using [`HashMap.entrySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29):

```
for (Entry <FileDetail, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    FileDetail key = entry.getKey();
    if (shouldProcess(key)) {
        ArrayList<String> list = entry.getValue();
        processList(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Having other restriction I choose to use the iteration only. However I liked Philipp Wendler's answer of wrapping the key, value in a object.

Answer (score 0):

We get the key object from Hashmap without iterating the keyset of HashMap by converting keyset to ArrayList. This is a simple example:

```
//Creating hashmap
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

//Adding elements into the map  
map.put("1", "Amit");
map.put("2", "Ananth");
map.put("3", "Sunil");

//Get the list from keyset
ArrayList myKeyList = new ArrayList(map.keySet());

//object to search in above map without iteration.
String myobj = "3";
System.out.println(myKeyList.get(myKeyList.indexOf(myobj)));
```

Comment: This **does** iterate through the list of all keys. `List.indexOf()` needs to do this in order to find the object. Also copying the keySet into the list needs iteration over the map. Just iterating over the keySet would be much cheaper than your solution.

Comment: Copying the keyset into list will take care of System.arraycopy() method. /**
           * @com.intel.drl.spec_ref
          */
         public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest,
                                       int destPos, int length) {
              VMMemoryManager.arrayCopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length);
          }. This would be faster.