# Getting a key from a HashMap using another object with its hashcode

Tags: java, dictionary, key

Say I have a Map that contains a very large quantity of objects, all of which contain a large amount of miscellaneous data which is ignored when comparing them (using `.equals()`). For example, this:

```
public class Complex {
    private long id;
    // Many other fields...

    // Methods, getters, setters...

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Complex other = (Complex) obj;
        if (id != other.id) // Note that only id is compared.
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would be able to easily find in constant time whether this map or set contained a key with a particular id, by using `myMap.get(new Complex(id));` or `mySetOrMap.contains(new Complex(id));`, but that unfortunately isn't what I need.

What I require is the entry, containing both the original key (which contains all the miscellaneous data) and the value.

My possible solutions are as follows:

- I could easily iterate through the hashmap, but that wouldn't be very elegant or fast.
- I could change the entire implementation of my map, so that it was a `Map<Long, Entry<Complex, MyValueType>>`, but this seems a little bit excessive.
- I could have another Map: `Map<Long, Complex>`, which is probably the most plausible.

In summary: Is there an elegant way to retrieve the original key used to create an entry in a map, assuming you have something with the same hashcode as it?

I did, after writing this, find a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248964/find-a-object-key-from-a-hashmap) from over 4 years ago, but was wondering if we could revise the answer (It was pre-Java 7).

Comment: Can you Explain a bit clearly? How does your current hashmap look like ?
`HashMap<Long,?>`

Comment: `I could have another Map: Map<Long, Complex>, which is probably the most plausible.` - I agree. I don't think there's any way to get the original key from the original Map without iterating over it, which is not efficient (there's probably a shorter way to write it with Java 8 Streams, but it would still involve iterating over the keySet or entrySet).

Comment: @karthik - It doesn't really matter what the value is, since It's irrelevant here (or so I thought?). But if you have an idea, just say Map<Complex, ValueType>

Answer (score 0):

You only have 2 choices:

a) you create a 2nd Map: `Map<Long, Complex>` to lookup the relevant `Complex`-object, like you already mentioned, or

b) you iterate over the Map, preferrably with a stream:

```
Long searchID = 42L;
    Map<Complex, MyValueType> x = new HashMap<Complex, MyValueType>();
    Entry<Complex, MyValueType> y = x.entrySet()
                                    .stream()
                                    .filter(e -> e.getKey().getId().equals(searchID))
                                    .findFirst()
                                    .orElse(null);
```

By the way: the same in xtend ("addon" to Java):

```
val Long searchID = 42L
val x = <Complex, MyValueType>newHashMap()
val y = x.filter[id==searchID]
```

I would not create a `Map<Long, Entry<Complex, MyValueType>>`

What is best for you depends on your "environment" -> how much RAM is free / how fast it needs to be. But I think there is no more "elegant" way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> I could change the entire implementation of my map, so that it was a Map<Long, Entry<Complex, MyValueType>>, but this seems a little bit excessive.

What's excessive about it? It's a mapping from your key to the data you're trying to get, which is exactly how Maps are supposed to be used. Of course using the `Entry` class as a general-purpose tuple comes with some issues, so instead you can define a new class `ComplexWithMyValueType` (perhaps with a better domain-specific name), to represent exactly the shape of data you're trying to retrieve. Then you can have a `Map<Long, ComplexWithMyValueType>`.